# How to configure the unicorn workers in gitlab-bitnami?

Tags: gitlab, bitnami

I install gitlab but with bitnami installation...and I need to change the unicorn workers to accelerate the server...but i can't find the configure file to change this parameter (worker_processes)....

Answer (score 0):

Since 8.16.3  version, Bitnami started to install GitLab using omnibus so if you have this version or a newer one you can follow the official gitlab documentation:

https://docs.gitlab.com/omnibus/settings/unicorn.html

If you are using gitlab 8.14.3 or lower, you are still using the gitlab installation from source code. In that case, unicorn is not used but mod_passenger plus apache. If you are using this configuration, please take a look at the optimization options for mod_passenger.

https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/config/apache/optimization/

You could update the `/opt/bitnami/apps/gitlab/conf/httpd-app.conf` file and then restart the apache server for the changes to take effect.